# How do you move your house you build in Creation mode in The Sims 3:Pets to a different lot?

Tags: the-sims-3

I looked through the tutorials and it mentions you can do it after you save your house to your studio which I have done but when I click the new lot it only comes up with other houses that aren't the one I created. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Long shot guess: is your saved house an incompatible size with the new lot? (is new lot shorter in one or both dimensions?)

Comment: I thought that could be the case but I built a house on a medium lot and tried to import it to a larger lot... :(

Answer (score 3):

1. Go back into your game
2. Save it
3. Edit town
4. Select the household
5. You have one of two options here:

   - Save household
   - Save household with house
6. Since you already saved the game from step 2, you can now kick the people in that house out (place them on clipboard)
7. Now you can save **only the house**.
8. Exit **without** saving
9. Now you can go back to your last save, everyone is still living in there and you also have the house in your library

Answer (score 1):

1. Edit Town
2. Bulldoze your property
3. Accept eviction
4. Move out with home
5. Click on family + save copy to library
6. Bulldoze property you want to move into
7. Replete 3, 4, 5
8. Click on YOUR family
9. Click "Place" button
10. Click lot you want
11. Move house in which direction you wish and accept
12. Save game
13. Main Menu
14. Click on your file
15. Add your family to house hold again

DONE